# Fibonacci program not working?

Tags: java, fibonacci

I'm trying to write a very simple Fibonacci sequence program.

```
import acm.program.*;
public class Fibonacci extends Program{
    public void run(){
        int i; 
        int fib1=1; 
        int fib2=0;
        int currentFib=0;
        int count = readInt("Until which Fibonacci number do you want to print? ");
        if(count>=0) println(0);
        if(count>=1) println(1);
        if (count>=2) {
            for (i=2; i<count; i++){
                currentFib = fib1+fib2;
                println(currentFib);
                fib1=fib2;
                fib2=currentFib;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However,for some reason when I write a number in cmd the only results are 0 and 1. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I can't really tell, since I started learning java a few days ago.

Comment: Show us how the readInt() method works.

Comment: Where are you printing the result if i > 2

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
    int fib1=1; 
    int fib2=0;
```

to

```
    int fib1=0; 
    int fib2=1;
```

Since fib1 should be initialized to fib(0) and fib2 should be initialized to fib(1).

Comment: True, but not really an answer to the question.

Comment: While it's probable that OP intended to start with 0 and 1, this isn't the source of his problem. In this case, with the starting numbers 1 and 0 (in that order), it should generate 1, 1, 2, 3, etc. Of course, this isn't the Fibonacci sequence because it doesn't start with the right numbers, but the same format should hold.

Comment: @masonsbro with the OPs code, 0,1,1,1,2,3,5,8... is produced. Fixing the initial values gives 0,1,1,2,3,5,8... which is the correct sequence.

Comment: @Eran I see what you mean. I would argue that the real problem there is that OP's code prints the first two terms out of order. Instead of printing 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, ... like the chosen starting values should produce, it prints a hard-coded 0 and 1 at the beginning. Changing the first two print statements to use variables instead of changing the starting numbers will make for a more flexible program. Nonetheless, the real problems are the use of less than instead of less than or equal to in the loop condition and not having a print statement in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to java world:-)

I see in your code, the value 0 and 1 is repeatedly assigned to fib1 and fib2.

Moreover where have you used your temp variable "I".

Better try doing these changes.

1. Replace the variable "i" with "fib2" in forloop.
2. Remove "currentfib" variable assignment. fib2 in forloop will be our "currentfib"
3. Print the addition of "fib1+fib2" directly.
4. Remove reassignment of "fib2" as well.